# Populate a select dropdown based on another select dropdown on Angular 14

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, auto-populate

so im trying to create a simple form with 2 select dropdowns. 
one select for the countries.
one select for their states.
the idea is to display a list of countries and when one country is selected, the second select gets populated with its main states. ( and obv maintaining data-binding )

I tried to use a simple list of strings for the countries which i succeded to populate the first select dropdown ( although i could not do a placeholder for the select idk why ) 
after that i declared a second object list with the the cities of each country then do a filter function to filter out only the list of states that are matching the selected country but i could not get to populate the second select dropdown with it.
Here is a stackblitz demo which explains better.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5sdwsj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need a proper filter function when the first dropdown has a value selected. Using an event like `ngModelChange` you can easily get the selected value and execute your filter to find the list of states.

component:

```
onCountrySelect(selectedCountry) {
    this.filteredStates = this.states.find(item => item.country === selectedCountry).stateList;
  }
```

html:

```
<form>
  <select name="countryName" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="onCountrySelect($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{ c }}">{{ c }}</option>
  </select>

  <select name="states" id="states" [(ngModel)]="selectedState">
    <option *ngFor="let s of filteredStates" value="{{ s }}">{{ s }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rexfrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: it's better use find instead of filter :)

Comment: just implemented the solution with filter function and it works like a charm ( i just discovered ngModelChange ) Thank you so much. if u can providea solution with find function if thats possible

Comment: Answer updated! Thanks everyone for the feedback :)